# Is there a way to tell which tests execute(cover) a particular class/method?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I am working on a brownfield project. And there are many tests which are supposed to validate the correctness of the system's behavior. However, I am not sure that there is a test for a particular code. In some cases, there is maybe more than one test for the code.

The question is - having a class(method) in my IDE, is there a way to know which tests are covering this piece of code?

It might refer to a code coverage, however, I am not interested in just knowing that the code was covered but rather I want to know which tests cover this code.